# Is it possible to obtain a history of messages via Viber API?

Tags: viber

According to the API documentation (http://developers.viber.com/api/rest-bot-api/index.html#viber-rest-api), there are not many functions available. I would like to clarify is there a way to get the history of messages using the API?

**Update** Because of this API is designed for creating bots, is there an approach to writing custom Viber clients? For instance, Telegram has API for this purpose: https://core.telegram.org/methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for you to obtain messages history from Viber but you can create list with history of received and sent messages on your side.

You can create custom service (client) in various technologies but here is example using [Java with Spring boot](https://github.com/Viber/viber-bot-java/tree/master/spring-boot-sample)

In this example you could create list in `SpringEchoBot` class. List would store all messagees recivied in `onMessageReceived` method and returned with `response.send()`.

So in short its up to you to create storage for message history and to manage it as you like.

Comment: Thanks, that was an obvious approach. This means there is no way to obtain any messages that have been posted before this client is started.

Comment: Thats right. Only exception is when you webhook is temporarily unavailable and Viber is trying to send messages to your bot. Messages get put in queue and are waiting for your webhook to become available again. 
Once your webhook is online again queue will empty itself. But this is unwanted behavior and does not serve as history.