# Is it possible to get all messages history from viber bot

Tags: php, wordpress, bots, chat, message

I found similar question [Is it possible to obtain a history of messages via Viber API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320543/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-history-of-messages-via-viber-api) but it was for java and mine bot is written with php. Can I make something similar using php?

Comment: As that post said, the answer to your direct question is **No, you cannot get all messages**. However, as that post also said, just create a Viber client which I've seen you asking questions about previously, so I think you know how to do that, and whenever you receive a message, store it in a database of your own choosing.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hi! Thank you for your answer! Yeah, I created a viber bot but I don't know how to save all messages in DB.  Can you help me? I'm using this bot: https://github.com/Bogdaan/viber-bot-php/blob/master/examples/bot-plus.php . i don't want to get all messages, I just want to save messages from bot or from user to have statistic what people chose.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what Viper is, but generally speaking, according to that other post and the [documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#webhooks), when using the webhook you can register an empty `event_types` parameter to receive all events. Do that and look at the data, and then work on the database. You could use a no-SQL system to store schema-less data, or you could determine the structure and make a schema. Regardless, you are out of Viper and into normal PHP and database world.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Viber is messanger and I wrote a bot for it. I just usually work with wordpress and other CMS and it's my first experience of writting chatbot. I just need to create `set_webhook.php` file  with This code: `{
   "url":"link on my viber bot",

   "send_name": true,
   "send_photo": true
}`